# c++ inheritance: Use parent method in child class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to c++, so I hope this question is not too stupid.

I want to have a method in my parent class which can be inherited and can be used in child classes, so I can always use the same functionality everywhere.

I run into a problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Unit {
public:
  string test = "Unit string";
  virtual void getString();
};

class Human: public Unit {
public:
  string test = "Human string";
  void getScString();
};


void Unit::getString()
{
    cout << "output:" << test; 
}
void Human::getScString()
{
   cout << "output:" << test; 
}


int main()
{
   Human tom  = Human();
   tom.getString(); // output:Unit string
   tom.getScString(); // output:Human string

   return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't tom.getString() do "output:Human string" ?

Do I really have to implement a method like getScString in every child class?

Comment: You're missing `virtual` ...

Comment: ... and a lot of other things.

Comment: @Jefffrey ... yup, I've just spotted that the method names don't match at all ...

Comment: The derived type does not override `getString()`, so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Use the `override` identifier and your compiler will tell you.

Comment: There is only getString() in the class Unit.  It uses the value of test in the class unit since there is no getString() in Human.

Comment: I thought it would be more like other programming languages, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not overridden `getString()`, so the base class method is being called, which will use `test` from the base class.

Answer (score 0):

`string Human::test` shadows string `Unit::test`.

You may use something like:

```
class Unit {
public:
  string test = "Unit string";
  void displayString() { std::cout << test << std::endl; } 
};

class Human: public Unit {
public:
  Unit() { test = "Human string"; };
};
```

or

```
class Unit {
public:
  virtual string getString() const { return "Unit string"; }
  void displayString() { std::cout << test << std::endl; } 
};

class Human: public Unit {
public:
  string getString() const override { return "Human string"; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the subclass Human You have two string members:

1. `Unit::test`  (or just `test` if you are in `Unit` scope)
2. `Human::test` (or just `test` if you are in `Human` scope)

Since you called to parent method from the Unit scope `getString` see only the `Unit` scope.

Classes are acting just like a namespace.

You can do it in c++ because the two variables declared in different namespaces or scopes.

just like you can declare variables with the same name in different scopes:

```
int i=0;
{
 int i=1;
 cout<<i; //will print the last = 1
}
cout<<i; //will print the first = 0
```